# Why can't I review suggested edits on beta site but lower-rep users can?

Tags: bug, beta-phase

I currently have the second-highest rep on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/review), which just went public beta.  [The Suggested Edits Review Queue](https://law.stackexchange.com/review) says, "You need at least 1k reputation to review suggested edits."  Presently only one user has that much rep.  But the queue shows that users with less than 100 rep are reviewing suggested edits.  What is going on?

Comment: From the duplicate: "Who can vote on a suggested edit?

    The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post."  The authors of the post still show up as "reviewers" even if they have never processed any posts beyond their own.